# Stacktrace Python

Tags: python, django

Have a app that is build in Python Django and Python.
The main is build in Django and some parts in Python.
Both lays on same server, but on diffrent locations.

But when i running the app I can't get any stacktrace from the Python scripts Im just getting a 500.

I can create a local server for Django scripts and get stacktrace, and I have try to redirect the Django app to load Python scripts from my C\: drive instead of the server, but can't get it to work.
I don't even know if is't possible.

But I need to create a local server/enviroment for the Python scripts to.

Any good ideas?

//

Comment: Why would you want a stacktrace? You normally get it when somethings wrong not when everything is okay.

Comment: If my scripts works it works, but when type something wrong I don't get any info about the fault, I only get a 500. So I can't develop. It is on my dev server I have this problem.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more on how the python scripts are getting called? By means of an import statement and then function calls?

Comment: I don't understand the difference you're making between "Django" and "Python". Django *is* Python. You can run any Python code directly in Django.

Comment: Yeah Django is Python, but the app is build with with some parts Django Framework and some part just Python. The Django part is main and front but some func is made by old python script's. The call is made by change the server location, it loads the cgi scripts from another location,

Comment: So, your question is actually, how can you get tracebacks for Python CGI scripts?

Answer (score 0):

On your development server you need to set the [`DEBUG`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#debug) flag to `True`.

Comment: I have done that, It works for Django scripts but not Python scipts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [try/except](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) blocks.

From Django:

```
# importing some external python script
import some_python_script

# Also needed
import traceback


# calling a function in the script and getting a stack trace when it goes wrong:
try:
    some_python_script.function_to_call()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not just a method im calling, it is the whole page, with sub page's. The old Python holds a about ten pages on the site. So it is a whole own part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution that is not the best, but it helps.
In the Python file I log the stacktrace.
For exampel:

```
try:
    some code
exception Exception, ex:
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logFile.log', level = logging.debug) 
    logging.exception(ex);
```